# MD5 Hash Base 64 conversion

Tags: java, vb.net

I have a code written in dot net for encryption and decryption methods. I need to implement this in Java. The code should have both encryption and decryption methods.

```
Private DES As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
Private MD5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
Private even As Integer = 1 'สำหรับบวกเพิ่มไปใน private key ของเดือนที่เป็นเลขคู่
Private odd As Integer = 2 'สำหรับบวกเพิ่มไปใน private key ของเดือนที่เป็นเลขคี่
Private Property key() As String
  Get
    Return GetKey()
  End Get

  Set(ByVal value As String)
  End Set
End Property

Private Function MD5Hash(ByVal value As String) As Byte()
  Return MD5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value))
End Function

Private Function GetKey() As String
  Dim yyyy As Integer = Year(Now)
  If yyyy > 2500 Then
    yyyy -= 543
  End If
  Dim mm As String = Right("0" & Month(Now), 2)
  Dim dd As String = Right("0" & Day(Now), 2)
  Dim key As Integer = dd & mm & yyyy

  If CInt(mm) Mod 2 = 0 Then
    key += even
  Else
    key += odd
  End If

  Return key
End Function

Public Function Encrypt(ByVal stringToEncrypt As String) As String
  DES.Key = MD5Hash(key)
  DES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
  Dim Buffer As Byte() = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt)
  Return Convert.ToBase64String(DES.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
End Function

Public Function Decrypt(ByVal encryptedString As String) As String
  Try
    DES.Key = MD5Hash(key)
    DES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
    Dim Buffer As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString)
    Return UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(DES.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
  Catch ex As Exception
    Return "Invalid Key, Decryption Failed."
  End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Don't use DES, it is not secure and has been superseded by AES which is no harder to use. 3DES should not be used for new work, again use AES.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do something by your own?

I'd like to bring that page to your attention: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/DESCrypterandDecrypter.htm